# Remove a sleep after a foreach loop

Tags: powershell, citrix

What this piece of a script does for every server in the reboot list it sends a reset command then sleeps for 1800 seconds

```
Foreach ($server in $rebootlist)
    {
        New-BrokerHostingPowerAction -Action Reset -AdminAddress $ddc -MachineName $server
    }
```

Sleep 1800(30 minutes) then continues onto the next part.

I have such a long sleep in there because I dont know another way

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Is there a way to move onto the next piece of the script? Normally I would use out-null or maybe start process so that when foreach piece is done it moves onto the next part.

Comment: what do you need the sleep for? to wait till every server is up again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if every server is up again before continue.

```
while ($i -lt $rebootlist.count){
    $i = 0
    foreach ($server in $rebootlist){
        if (Test-Connection $server -count 1 -ErrorAction ignore){
            $i++
        }
        else{
            Write-Verbose "$server offline"
        }
    }
    sleep -Seconds 1
}
```